# Encrypting Querystring and Decrypting it in PHP

Tags: php, get, query-string, encryption

I have the following Encryption Classs in php

```
define(ENCRYPTION_KEY,"abcdegef");
define(INITIALIZATION_VECTOR,mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_DES, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND));

function EncryptString($input)
{
    $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, ENCRYPTION_KEY, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, INITIALIZATION_VECTOR);
    return base64_encode($encrypted_string);
}

function DecryptString($encryptedInput)
{
    $decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_DES, ENCRYPTION_KEY, base64_decode($encryptInput), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, INITIALIZATION_VECTOR);
    return $decrypted_string;
}
```

---

And have url on anchor tag with querystring which i am encrypting

```
<a href="SomePage.php?action=<?php include_once ('EncryptionLibrary.php');
echo EncryptString("IamData"); ?>
```

When I am trying to decrypt it on SomePage.php using following code .. I am getting decrypted value incorrect

```
if (isset($_GET["action"]))
{
        echo trim(DecryptString($_GET["action"]));
}
```

Comment: I am encrypting by
<a href="SomePage.php?action=<\?php include_once('EncryptionLibrary.php'); echo  EncryptString("IamData"); \?>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `INITIALIZATION_VECTOR` is different each time.  For modes that use an IV you need the same one for encryption and decryption.

Comment: Options. (a) Use a mode (like EBC) that doesn't use an IV. (b) Send the IV to the page (it doesn't need to be secret). (c) Create the IV once, by hand. Hardcode it [*], perhaps using serialize and unserialize.  [*] I can't believe I'm advising you to hardcode data.  Don't tell anyone I said that.