# Writing parameters to a database and link encryption

Tags: php, get

i am writing to my database using the parameters that i get from a link.

consider the following link:

```
mywebsite.com/index.php?ud=33&nt=117&g=Yes
```

if i play with the link and change the values it will write to the database wrong data, what are the available ways to prevent this from happening?

note that the links are to be clicked from an email message

what i am thinking of is a one time authentication key per message that works one time only but that will cost alot of space on the databas, is there a better way?

Comment: you could add simple string encryption.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypting Querystring and Decrypting it in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914763/encrypting-querystring-and-decrypting-it-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that sensitive data shouldn't be in querystring.

Follow these steps:

1 - Before write the link to the database, you should check as part of your business rule if the parameters are consistent and the user has permission to access it.

2 - Then, you should think which params of the querystring should be in plain text (i.e. inside the link stored in the database). For example, if you keep an ID of an entity into the querystring and send to the database, you must think if there will problems in the case that the mentioned entity is deleted. Since your querystring is in plain text, no cascade will be performed. In this case, the best approach is to convert the query string into data and store it in the database as foreign keys instead of querystring. Then, you can recover the full link by constructing it at application level.

---

Another tip:

Since you are sending the link by e-mail, you can convert the string in plain text (in your scenario, `ud=33&nt=117&g=Yes`) by running an encryption algorithm to convert all this to  one single encrypted string. You would have something like `mywebsite.com/index.php?c=IJNWEI7we876fWEPOWOKEMF`. It is less user-friendly and play-proof.

Hope it helps.